# Googe Apps Script - Los permisos en el manifiesto no se guardan

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un código en un GSheet que está enlazado a un formulario. Ya configuré el activador para cada que el formulario es contestado. Por medio del código quiero que me haga una copia de una plantilla para hacer la correspondencia con las respuestas del forms, para luego convertirla en PDF y enviarla por correo.

El problema es a la hora de llegar a la función
`var doc=DocumentApp.openById(idArchivoCopia)`.
La consola me arroja el error diciendo que el documento es inaccesible.

Ya intenté darle los permisos en el manifiesto "appsscript.json" y ahí es donde me sigo atorando ya que por alguna razón no me está guardando la edición. Se queda "Guardando" como ven en la imagen.

Ya también me cambié de red, pensando en una intermitencia del internet pero no.
En otra pregunta que hacían, sugerían asociar mi proyecto en GCP pero no es viable ya que pertenezco a una organización y no estoy del todo seguro que me lo aprueben.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]